# Puppet agent runs as a daemon but manifests are only applied when puppet agent is run manually?

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster

I have puppet agent daemonized

```
# service puppet status
 * agent is running
```

And can confirm that it is retrieving the configurations from the master

```
# cat /var/lib/puppet/state/last_run_summary.yaml | grep last
    last_run: 1385262693
# date --date @1385262693
Sun Nov 24 03:11:33 UTC 2013
```

However changes I made to configurations hours since the `last_run` are not being applied.  They are only applied if I run

```
# puppet agent --test
```

Why are the configurations not being applied when puppet is daemonized?

**Here are the contents of `/etc/puppet/puppet.conf` on my puppet client**

```
[main]
logdir=/var/log/puppet
vardir=/var/lib/puppet
ssldir=/var/lib/puppet/ssl
rundir=/var/run/puppet
factpath=$vardir/lib/facter
templatedir=$confdir/templates
prerun_command=/etc/puppet/etckeeper-commit-pre
postrun_command=/etc/puppet/etckeeper-commit-post
pluginsync=true

[master]
# These are needed when the puppetmaster is run by passenger
# and can safely be removed if webrick is used.
ssl_client_header = SSL_CLIENT_S_DN
ssl_client_verify_header = SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY

[agent]
server = puppetmaster.website.com
```

Comment: paste ur puppet.conf on the client.... you may have the wrong value for puppet server

Comment: I've pasted the contents of `/etc/puppet/puppet.conf`.  The address of the server the agent is contacting is a FQDN which requires DNS to resolve.

Comment: I am a bit confused why you have a `[master]` section on your clients.  Are you seeing anything getting logged into your puppet logs on the client?

Comment: run "puppet agent -t --server=puppetmaster.website.com" to make sure that entry is correct....

Comment: moderator deleted my answer, but try specifying the puppet master on cli as per example above

Comment: @nandoP: Your original 'answer' was converted to a comment. If you want you should be able to add another answer.

Comment: i dont think theres really anything to add here... lets just wait for OP to verify puppet master and/or resolution

Comment: @user784637 So that last run time is from a run within the daemon, not  a manual `--test` run, right?  Can you review your system logs for what's going on in those runs?

Comment: @nandoP @Iain running `puppet agent -t --server=puppetmaster.website.com` via cli casuses everything to work correctly.  @Zoredache the `[master]` section was there by default when I installed puppet on the puppet clients.  Would removing it fix this problem?

Comment: @ShaneMadden This is from `/var/log/syslog` whenever the daemon runs... `(/File[/var/lib/puppet/lib]) Failed to generate additional resources using 'eval_generate: SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey:: key values mismatch`  however it runs perfectly when I do it manually with `$ puppet agent --test`.  Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @user784637 Ahh - what user is the daemon running as, and what user are you when you run `puppet agent --test`?

Comment: @ShaneMadden The daemon is running as root as `ps auxf | grep puppet` shows `root     27284  0.1 11.4 151576 57448 ?        Ss   Nov22   2:58 /usr/bin/ruby1.8 /usr/bin/puppet agent`  I always run `puppet agent --test` as root

Comment: @user784637 That seems very strange.  Is the time synced fairly decently between the master and agent?  Maybe nuke and regenerate the client's SSL certificate?

Comment: yes, agreed..... strange puppet client issues can be solved by "puppet cert clean fqdn" on master, and "rm -fv /path/to/cert/file" on client..... then run puppet agent, and its as if you are doing so for first time

Comment: @ShaneMadden @nandoP The issue was solved by by removing the puppetmaster cert on the puppet master `puppetca clean puppetmaster.website.com` which removed the puppetmaster ssl .pem key. After that I regenerated the puppet master cert `sudo puppet master --no-daemonize --verbose`, cleared/regenerated the client cert and everything worked out =).